# $z_1, z_2, z_3\in\mathbb C$ satisfy $|z_1-3|=|z_2-3|=|z_3-3|$ and $\arg(\frac{z_3-z_1}{z_2-z_1})=\pi/6$, compute $z_2^2+z_3^2-3z_2-3z_3-z_2z_3+10$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, locus

let $z_{1}, z_{2}, z_{3}$ be three complex number such that $|z_{1}-3|=|z_{2}-3|=|z_{3}-3|$ and $\arg(\frac{z_{3}-z_{1}}{z_{2}-z_{1}})=\pi/6$

then what is the value of $z_{2}^2+z_{3}^2-3z_{2}-3z_{3}-z_{2}*z_{3}+10$

**my approach:**

I identified that the three complex numbers lie on a circle of variable radius and given center and the argument relation gave use difference between angles subtend by any two of them from origin but I couldn't use this to create the relation of the value they have asked

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $w_1=z_1-3, w_2=z_2-3, w_3=z_3-3$, then
$$|w_1|=|w_2|=|w_3|=:r>0,\qquad \arg\left(\frac{w_3-w_1}{w_2-w_1}\right)=\frac\pi6,$$
and
\begin{align*}
z_{2}^2+z_{3}^2-3z_{2}-3z_{3}-z_{2}z_{3}+10=w_2^2+w_3^2-w_2w_3+1.
\end{align*}

[image: Picture]

We use the geometric meaning of complex numbers. Draw a circle $C$ in the $xOy$ plane centering at the origin with raduis $r$. Let $P, Q, R$ denote $w_1, w_2, w_3$ respectively, then $w_3-w_1$ corresponds to the vector $\vec{PR}$ and $w_2-w_1$ corresponds to the vector $\vec{PQ}$. The condition $\arg\left(\frac{w_3-w_1}{w_2-w_1}\right)=\frac\pi6$ implies that $\angle QPR=\frac\pi6$ and $P, Q, R$ lies in a counterclockwise manner. Hence $\angle QOR=\frac\pi3$ and thus $w_3=\eta w_2$ with $\eta=e^{\frac\pi3i}=\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}2i$. Therefore,
$$w_2^2+w_3^2-w_2w_3=(\eta^2-\eta+1)w_2^2=0.$$
Hence
$$z_{2}^2+z_{3}^2-3z_{2}-3z_{3}-z_{2}z_{3}+10=w_2^2+w_3^2-w_2w_3+1=1.$$

Comment: I uploaded a picture here trying to visualize the geometric stuff, although I think the words  are enough to say what I mean. However, in my country, all pictures in this site cannot be loaded, so I can't see how my picture looks like here. If someone happens to be passing by my answer, please kindly let me know whether it looks good or not. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The image looks perfect

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad Thank you very much!  :)

Comment: @Feng this is perfect. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score -1):

This implies that triangle formed by $3, z_2, z_3$ as vertices is equilateral

It is well known that $a,b,c$ represent vertices of an equilateral triangle iff

$a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca =0$ i.e. $z_2^2+z_3^2+9 - 3z_2-3z_3-z_2z_3 = 0$ so that given expression equals $1$